# Propagating QueryString parameter in RedirectToAction calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, redirecttoaction

I want to make sure that a particular parameter in the QueryString, in my case the `request_id` is propagated to the redirected action.

Say for example, I have an Action `First`,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult First() 
{
    ////////////////////
    // Lots of code ...
    ////////////////////

    return RedirectToAction("Second");
}
```

Now say, the `First` postback had a parameter in the `QueryString`, which I would like to pass to the `Second` action. One way to do it would be to pass the value in the `RedirectToAction` call itself,

```
string requestId = Request.QueryString[REQUEST_ID_KEY];
return RedirectToAction("Second", new { REQUEST_ID_KEY = requestId });
```

But I have to do this in a series of Actions and I am unwilling to incorporate request id propagation logic inside the action. It would be better if I could incorporate this inside an `ActionFilter`, but I cant figure out how to add parameters to the QueryString from an ActionFilter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
public class PreserveQueryStringAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var redirectResult = filterContext.Result as RedirectToRouteResult;
        if (redirectResult == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var query = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        // Remark: here you could decide if you want to propagate all
        // query string values or a particular one. In my example I am
        // propagating all query string values that are not already part of
        // the route values
        foreach (string key in query.Keys)
        {
            if (!redirectResult.RouteValues.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                redirectResult.RouteValues.Add(key, query[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
[PreserveQueryString]
public ActionResult First() 
{
    ////////////////////
    // Lots of code ...
    ////////////////////

    return RedirectToAction("Second");
}
```

Comment: @Darin .. Just for the knowledge.. May I know what is the advantage of this implementation over Session or TempData?

Comment: @alok_dida, TempData uses Session behind the scenes. Personally I never use Session in my applications. I prefer designing them in a stateless and RESTful manner. So since I disable the session in web.config (`<sessionState mode="Off" />`), well, Session and TempData don't apply for me.

Comment: @Darin .. Oks. One more question(I hope you don't get irritate with my bunch of questions), I am implementing one application which uses form authentication. I want to keep the logged in user's "UserID" through out the application. How can I implement this scenario without using Session? I am using MVC 3.

Comment: @alok_dida, that's already implemented for you by the Forms Authentication module. The currently logged in user is stored in a cookie and you can retrieve it in every action using the `User.Identity.Name` property. You don't really need to do anything in order to achieve that.

Comment: @Darin, oks thanks. I do not know about that. What about some other properties which I want to keep through out the application?

Comment: It will very much depend on the properties. You could extend the authentication mechanism and store them in the userData part of the authentication cookie. Another possibility is to simply store them in the database and when needed fetch them from there.

Comment: In .netcore you will use Request.Query instead of Request.QueryString. Hope it helps someone

Comment: In .net core, I was using RedirectToAction, so I added an if/else to this for RedirectToActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in subsequent action than please add it that param in Session or TempData (But need to re-assign in each action) so you dont need to pass it as a querystring in each action. In case of session, once you done with all actions than remove that key from the Session.

Comment: I will need the data in the postback too .. so I have to pass it in the QueryString

Comment: You will easily get the data from Session till you dont remove the key from the session so that data will be available in postback action too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blogpost I wrote on how to fluently [add querystring parameters in the action](http://ubcoder.blogspot.com/2012/07/add-querystring-parameter-to-aspnet-mvc.html)